# Is it possible to remove 'Currently' label when using django-stdimage?

Tags: python, django, imagefield, django-widget

I am using `django-stdimage` in my Django app and it works great, the only problem is that I want to remove the 'Currently' string, the clear checkbox and the rest of the decoration from the HTML template. I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Here is the StdImageField declaration inside my `models.py`:

```
photo = StdImageField(upload_to=join('img', 'agents'),
                      variations={'thumbnail': (100, 100, True)}, default=None,
                      null=True, blank=True, )
```

I have read several SO answer about modifying the ImageField widget to use the class `ClearableFileInput` but it seems that the `widget` attribute is not allowed as a `StdImageField` class parameter.

Is there a way to remove all this decoration?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove where? in forms? in the admin?

Comment: remove/hide them In the HTML template. I suppose I have to make some modifications in models.py or forms.py

Comment: @juankysmith I might be wrong, but it seems that `StdImageField` operates only at models level. Can't you use `ImageField` with custom widget in your forms.py and `StdImageField` in your models.py?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `StdImageField` [extends](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage/blob/2.4.1/stdimage/models.py#L146) Django's `ImageField`

Django's `ImageField` [defines](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.5/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L488) `'form_class': forms.ImageField`

and Django's `forms.ImageField` default widget is: `ClearableFileInput`

So if you want to change this widget on a `model.fields` level, you need to extend `StdImageField` and override the `formfield` method to return a `form_class` with a `form.field` having another default widget.

A simple example solution should look like this:

```
class NotClearableImageField(forms.ImageField):
    widget = forms.FileInput


class MyStdImageField(StdImageField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'form_class': NotClearableImageField})
        return super(MyStdImageField, self).formfield(**defaults)

# Now you can use MyStdImageField
# in your model instead of StdImageField
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_image = MyStdImageField(*args, **kwargs)
```

but this will be a change affecting all `ModelForm`'s extending your `Model` (including the Django admin).

You maybe don't want to do that, what you can do instead is to apply this widget override only on a single `form` where you want this specific behavior. `ModelForms` already support this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'my_image': forms.FileInput(),
        }
```

Now you can use this form class on the places where you want the change.

Comment: Thanks! setting the widget of the field as FileInput() was enough